# php - eliminate the space in the beginning while writing to CSV file

Tags: php

I am writing array values to a CSV file using PHP. In the array values, I have included a line break using `\n`. After the array values are updated, I am using the implode function as below.

```
$newLine[] = $row[$i].",";
$newLine[] = "\n";
$csv2 [] = implode(" ", $newLine);
```

However, while writing to the CSV file, an extra space gets appended to the front of the line. This is causing me some problems in display. I want to eliminate the space in front of the line while it is getting written. I tried to do the below.

```
$line1 =  str_replace(' .','.',$line);
```

However, I am not able to write without the space in beginning to the CSV file.

Comment: Have you tried [trim](http://www.php.net/trim)?

Comment: You really shouldn't construct CSV manually. [Use `fputcsv()` instead.](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) It will handle all the intricacy of escaping and quoting.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Use [fputcsv()](http://nz2.php.net/fputcsv) and save yourself a headache.

Comment: I am using fwrite () to put into CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use spaces at all:

```
$newLine[] = $row[$i].",";
$csv2 [] = implode("\n", $newLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv2[] = trim ( implode("\n", $newLine) , "\n");
```

This should work since it removes only line breaks at the beginning and end of the string.